# Which product category has seen the max value of returns in the last 3 months of transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1) Product Table - where the columns are prod_cat = clothing, footwear, electronics and prod_cat_code = 1,2,3 respectively.

2) Transaction Table - where columns are prod_cat_code = 1,2,3 ; Tran_date with latest date being 28-02-2014 and Total_amt (having positive and negative values)

I want to find the product category which has seen the max value of returns in the last 3 months of transactions.

The query i am using here in MYSQL 2014 is -

```
SELECT Tran_date,
    Max(Total_amt)
    FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE Tran_date >= DATEADD(day, 90, 28-02-2014)
Group By Tran_date, Total_amt
Order By (Total_amt) desc
```

But this is giving me blank columns.

How can i frame a query for this as well as for selecting a product category?

Comment: 28 minus 2 minus 2014 =1988. Note that there are whole books, manuals, and tutorials dedicated to the basics of SQL.

Comment: If your code works, it is SQL Server code, not MySQL.  Plus, "2014" is a release of SQL Server.  MySQL has release numbers like 8.0.  Also, how do YOU define "return".  Sample data and desired results would help.  And if you want the last three months of transactions, why is there a date from 2014 in the sample code?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Returns are defined in the total_amt column and i want the last three months of transactions from the date data provided in the table. It has old data. So as per the tables i want last 3 months transactions wherein the latest date in table is 28-02-2014. So 3 months time span would be before 28-02-2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 1 prod_cat , sum(total_amt) as total_return_amount 
From transactions as t 
inner join prod_cat_info as p 
on t.prod_subcat_code=p.prod_sub_cat_code and t.prod_cat_code = p.prod_cat_code
Where t.total_amt < 0 and 
t.tran_date >= dateadd(month, -3 , date_add(max(t.tran_date)))
Group by p.prod_cat
Order by p.prod_cat desc ;
```

Answer (score -1):

MySQ2014 ? Do you mean sql server 2014 as DATEADD looks like MSSQL.

I make the assumption that returns are negative transactions. I also make the assumption that you want to get the product category, that cumulatively for the previous 90 days from '28-02-2014' had the largest value of returns. It would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    prod_cat_code
    ,SUM(Total_amt) as totalreturns
    FROM TRANSACTIONS
WHERE Tran_date >= DATEADD(day, -90, '28-02-2014')
    AND Total_amt < 0
GROUP BY prod_cat_code
ORDER BY totalreturns ASC
```

Comment: Top is not a MySQL construct. Plus, there's far too much wrong with the OP's query to address here.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . This is clearly not a MySQL question -- as the OP explains.  MySQL has no version 2014 and the OP says that the code runs but produces incorrect results.  You shouldn't downvote such an answer.  You should address the database issue with the OP.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query would run, in MySQL, without generating any syntax error. By all means disagree with me, but please don't lecture me on what *I* should be doing.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . It is news to me that MySQL has a function called `dateadd()` that takes three arguments.